# I want to iterate through messages and timestamp of a slack channel in python

Tags: python, webclient, slack-api

I have wrote the following in order to iterate through messages of a slack channel:

What if you want to iterate through the 'text' and 'ts' only? I have wrote the following myself but im getting an error

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import os
from slack import WebClient
from slack.errors import SlackApiError
import datetime

client = WebClient(token=os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"])
channel_to_listen = os.environ['CHANNEL_TO_LISTEN']

def main():
    response = client.conversations_history(channel=channel_to_listen, limit= 10)
    messages = response['messages']

    for message in messages:
        timestamp = messages['ts']
        content = messages['text']
        print(timestamp + " " + content)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Im getting this error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

If i add index in messages:

```
messages = response['messages'][0]
```

Then it will print 10 times or as many times as i have in limit attribute the same timestamp and same text, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace messages with message in your loop

Comment: Thank you mate. That's why I'm not developing for a living I guess hahaha. Thanks again